# How to include string variable of html code in javascript response?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

In my controller's show action we are prepping a bunch of information for building out an html table that is returned to the browser via jquery replacing the div the table is in.

This one part is being interpreted as just plain text and not added to the table.  So I'm doing something wrong with the encoding, I gather, but what I've tried so far hasn't improved the result.

The controller's show action, in part:

```
@shared_individuals = Individual.where(:address_id => params[:id]).order("birthdate ASC")
@typecodes = Contactmethods.select("Distinct typecode_desc, typecode_id")
@contact_methods = getem( @typecodes, @shared_individuals)
```

getem() is function in the controller that does a lot of hairy arrangement and html coding for the table, but to simplify to try and figure out what's wrong it is presently just doing this:

```
def getem( @typecodes, @shared_individuals )
   foo = "<tr><td>Testing</td></tr>"
   return foo
end
```

The controller's show action is called as an AJAX transaction, so the view code is show.js.erb:

```
$('#selected_family')
    .replaceWith('<div id="selected_family">' +
        '<%=j render partial: "addresses/selected_address", object: @selected_address %>' +
        '<table border="1px" rules=all frame=box cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">' +
            '<tr>' +
                '<th></th><%=j render partial: "review/first_names", collection: @shared_individuals %>' +
            '</tr>' +
            '<tr>' +
                '<td><strong>Birthday</strong></td><%=j render partial: "review/birth_dates", collection: @birth_dates %>' +
            '</tr>' +
            '<tr>' +
                '<td><strong>Phone</strong></td><%=j render partial: "review/phone_numbers", collection: @phone_numbers %>' +
            '</tr>' +
            '<tr>' +
                '<td><strong>Email</strong></td><%=j render partial: "review/emails", collection: @emails %>' +
            '</tr>' +
            '<%=j @contact_methods %>' +
        '</table>' +
        '</div>')
    .show("blind");
```

So the flow is that the show method has populated @contact_methods with a string of HTML code that I'm asking erb to insert into the HTML in the javascript response.

What actually happens in the browser is that ABOVE the table we see

```
< tr>< td>Testing< /td>< /tr>
```

(The html tags aren't really spaced out, but I couldn't figure out how to get the stackoverflow markup language to leave them alone)
and then the table represented correctly, but without that row included within it.

I tried:

```
   '<%=h @contact_methods %>' +  #wasn't that from Rails 1.0? 
   '<%=  @contact_methods %>' +  #nothing shows up
```

I even tried:

```
   '#{@contact_methods}' + #but of course that's silly in this context
```

and why not:

```
   @contact_methods + #that blows up the javascript processing
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem a different way, one which conforms a bit better to MVC conventions: The controller creates a collection of all the data the view will need but doesn't wrap it in HTML.  The partials do all the HTML wrapping.  And then paying attention to the difference between <% ... %> and <%= ... %> is always smart, too!